# How to delete all rows except the last 2 from a google sheet using a Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to delete all rows except the last 2 from a google sheet.
The number of rows can vary.
But I need always the last 2 rows.

How should be the script to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your comment on the other answer, perhaps this will help you.

```
function myfunc101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('DailyHelpDesk');
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const nr = 2;//number of rows to leave at the bottom
  const rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr - nr + 1,sh.getLastColumn());
  sh.deleteRow(sr,rg.getNumRows());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have this:                                                                        function DELETEROWS() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily Stand-Up Helpdesk NOC');

start = 1; 
howManyToDelete = sheet.getLastRow() - 2; 
sheet.deleteRows(start, howManyToDelete);
}

Comment: 20:07:15 Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null
DELETEROWS @ Código.gs:6

Comment: No need to get the range, `sh.getLastRow() - sr - nr + 1` is already the number of rows to be deleted. @LuisCarlosBalma You have to change `DailyHelpDesk` from the provided code to an existing sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

```
// getting sheet to work on
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(<sheet name goes here>);

start = 1; // Hard coded row number from where to start deleting
howManyToDelete = sheet.getLastRow() - 2; // Leaving the last two rows

sheet.deleteRows(start, howManyToDelete);
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm new: how can I use this script for a worksheet called "DailyHelpDesk"? I have to name the worksheet into the script I supposed...

Comment: Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null

Comment: can you share what you are trying to run here

Comment: Here is what I'm running:

Comment: function DELETEROWS() {
  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily Stand-Up Helpdesk NOC');

start = 1; // Hard coded row number from where to start deleting
howManyToDelete = sheet.getLastRow() - 2; // Leaving the last two rows

sheet.deleteRows(start, howManyToDelete);
}

Comment: 8:23:50 Aviso Se ha iniciado la ejecución
8:23:50 Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null
DELETEROWS @ Código.gs:6

Comment: Please verify that you have ran the script from the sheet you are intending to achieve the delete operation on.

Comment: From the sheet I go to "Tools" and then to "Script Editor". And it opens the Apps Script page where I write the script. So, how can I ran the script from the sheet I want to work with?

Comment: The sheet is open when I run the script. Even in General Information, it has the number of executions of the script using the sheet.

Comment: Its working now! The name of the sheet was incorrect. I changed it using the name of the tab of the sheet.

Comment: Now I'm trying to automate the script to use it every time the sheet is open